# smooth scrolling how to use excerpting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, smooth-scrolling

I have this code and it works well.

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '')
    && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }
}
```

});

But also I have some elements and I don't want apply smooth scrolling for them! How can I do it ?
Example   -  http://codepen.io/zoom/pen/ggYaXZ
 I don't want aplly it to <`li><a href="#apple">Scroll to Section Apple</a></li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some other `data-` attribute:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"]):not([data-no-smooth-scroll])').click(function() {
```

And inside your `html` add `data-no-smooth-scroll="true"` to the relevant link:

```
<a href="#apple" data-no-smooth-scroll="true">Scroll to Section Apple</a>
```

Here is a fork to your codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNbYKe

Answer (score 0):

You could make an `if` statement that would remove the smooth scrolling for every element that has some class, i.e. `class="notThis"`.

In this case, you have to add that class to the `#apple` link element: `<a class="notThis" href="#apple">Scroll to Section Apple</a>`.

It would be something like this

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") !== "notThis"){
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);
    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks For The Thought

Comment: please give it a point if you thought it was useful for you :)